# Get user domain groups list using the API without admin privileges

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-admin-sdk, google-people-api

I need to get list of user domain groups without Admin. Admin sdk can do this, but only with admin account of domain. As I see, google Sheets can search groups of my domain and share documents to group’s users. I need to do something similar on my site.

Comment: Are you trying to list groups within your domain without using Admin SDK? Do you want to achieve this programmatically (through Google Services / APIs)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this highly depend on your environment setup. You might need to make a new "admin role" granting explicitly "Admin API privileges" with "Groups>Read" permission, and assign this role to whoever needs to access that data.

[image]

Note that **API** privileges are separate from the **console** privileges
You can read more about it here : https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?hl=en